# Undo: export GIT_ASKPASS="<password goes here>"

Tags: git, github, rsa, gitlab

I'm relatively new to git/gitlab. For my school gitlab account, I was trying to setup `git push` to not continuously ask for my rsa passphrase by using:

```
export GIT_ASKPASS="<password goes here>"
```

It did not work, and now I'm stuck trying to push to gitlab with a refused connection. Is there an easy way out? Or do I have to setup my rsa keys all over again? Thanks in advance for helping a noob in distress.

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  Try Superuser.

Comment: Here's a hint too:, git_askpass specifies a program, not a password.  See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best at first to generate ssh keys without a passphrase.
Or you would have to deal with ssh-agent, as described in "[Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent)"

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "key for xxx access" -q -P ""
```

Publish your public key to your GitLab account, and it should not ask for a passphrase (provided you are using a `git@gitlab.com:<username>/<reponame>` **ssh** url, not an https one)

Comment: So going back to my issue, the way around my problem is to generate a new ssh key without a passphrase?

Comment: @steal_1234 yes. And GIT_ASKPASS is for https url. SSH_ASKPASS might work (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreaskPass), but again, test first without a passphrase